# Did Visual Basic ever restrict where variables could be declared like C90?

Tags: vba, vb.net, vb6

Busy working on an old VB6 project, recently converted to VB.NET. The application was originally written in the 1990s, and all variable declarations (`Dim dbVersion As Single` and so on) are crammed together at the top of methods, generally out-of-sight from where the variable is used.

The style of "declare all variables at the top of the function" was commonplace in the 90s, enforced in the C90 and earlier K&R versions of the C language. Some languages, such as Delphi, still use this declarative style. But the C99 and later C-standards, C++, C# and modern VB.NET allow for variables to be declared wherever they are used (IMO, a huge improvement).

My question is whether there was ever a time when this style was enforced in Visual Basic or VBA (or indeed VB.NET)?

Comment: I've just checked in VB6 and you can indeed declare a variable anywhere within a subroutine or function, **including** within a code block. **However** it looks as if the scope is slightly different to the VB.net scope which is detailed in the MS documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope). In VB6 you can still access the value of a variable _after_ the code comes out of the block where the variable is declared, whereas the .Net docs on Block Scope do not allow access outside the block.

Comment: Kudos to that legacy dev for going with `dbVersion` instead of `sngDbVersion` though.

Comment: Given the scoping rules for VB, I'd guess that up-front declaration was required at one point in the lineage, but I don't know when that would have changed.  I *think* in VB3 it still would have been necessary, but it's been so long since I used it (going on 30 years) I no longer remember.  The big re-architecture in VB4 (which I think is the point where the language engine was merged with the Office VBA) seems like an obvious place for this to have changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggested, taught in schools as a "best practice", but no, not *enforced* by the compiler - not to the extent that a declaration *must* appear before any executable statement in a procedure scope, no.

VB6/VBA code can declare locals anywhere within a procedure scope (the smallest possible scope in VB6/VBA); the catch is that `Dim` (and `Const`, also legal in local scope) statements aren't executable (you can't break on them), and I would guess the reason it was so warmly recommended to "just put them all at the top" is that local declarations *must* appear before the first use of a variable: having a block of declarations therefore ensures all local declarations are legal.

> **Caveat:** `ReDim` statements *are* executable, *and* they act as a `Dim` declaration. It is perfectly legal to have `ReDim someArray(1 To maxValue)` even if `someArray` wasn't previously declared, even with `Option Explicit` specified.

But having a block of declarations at the top of a procedure isn't a *modern* best practice...

> *[...] are crammed together at the top of methods, generally out-of-sight from where the variable is used.*

...and IMO *this* is exactly why.

VB.NET changed the rules of scoping a bit (you can now have an inner scope inside a procedure), but what it *really* did was to introduce a knowledge gap tight enough that VB6 devs wouldn't be too intimidated, but wide enough that the new language & framework could boast a new set of best practices - and the onboarding devs would just embrace them. New language, new ways: out with Hungarian Notation and walls of declarations at the top of procedure scopes - and just like that, the new recommendation was to declare variables where & as you need them, and to never prefix any identifier with a type abbreviation.

But much of the VBA crowd weren't devs, and didn't hop onto the .NET bandwagon, and essentially missed the memo with the updated best practices that could effectively apply in VBA/VB6 even though they were pushed for VB.NET. VBA/VB6 isn't necessarily stuck in 1997 though; the [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) project (open-source, I manage it) aims to modernize the VBE, its tooling (static code analysis, refactorings, unit testing, etc.), and the coding practices around it.

Comment: What a great, informative answer! Also, I have to say I love your "About Me" in your profile :-D

Comment: Good answer, as it addresses whether VB6/VBA ever enforced this syntactic rule (no). It doesn't, however, address whether earlier versions of VB ever enforced this rule, but TBH this is not so relevant to me. The rant about Hungarian Notation is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @AlainD thanks! The earliest VB version I used was VB4, and before that QuickBasic (or QBasic?); I don't recall it being enforced back then either, but can't back it up with anything other than foggy memory, so I left it out. The rant against HN puts the rest of the "best practices" in perspective though: sticking all declarations at the top of a scope *as a best practice* is just as irrational as sticking HN prefixes everywhere. That said seeing HN in new VB code in 2021 *is* a pet peeve of mine, working on it. ;-)

Comment: JFYI, HN is alive and kicking, no plans to give up on it here because VBIDE does not deal with single letter variables very well (e.g. X and Y on mouse events) and because we can’t be fooled twice by MS. . .

Comment: I'm with @wqw on HN. Certainly excessive use is brain-damaged, and its not so useful in .NET where everything is an object anyway, but in strongly-typed or memory-constrained applications, judicious use of HN can occasionally be helpful. Ranting about HN *per se* is as pointless as discussions about whether Golf is a better sport than Rugby. Thankfully HN is far less commonplace these days and where used, generally more sensibly.

Comment: I started using VB with v3 and from thereon, VB3 included, the placement of the declaration was never enforced. What I learned as best practice back then was the fact that all declarations should be put at the top of the procedure, as - as explained by @MathieuGuindon, the smallest possible scope was at procedure level. Thus putting them all at the top was considered better than sprinkling them "all over the place" within the procedure. Keep also in mind that `Option Explicit` (=enforcing variable declaration) never was a mandatory nor default setting = bad coding ensued. :-/